# rails_admin: How to change a field value when another field has changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I'm running rails_admin 1.4.2 and I have the following scenario:

On create form I have a field (boolean) that when checked I want other field to have its value changed but still editable. I was (unsuccessfully) trying something like:

```rb
create do
  field :my_boolean_field_to_be_changed do
    formatted_value do
      value = bindings[:object].my_boolean_field
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Rails admin does not provide any facilities to do this dynamically (without a page reload) you'd have to do it in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can override in model layer

```
class Test
    before_create do
       [do something]
    end
    
    before_update do
       [do something]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a partial file and update from JS and query paramters:
partial:

```
<div class="field controls">
<%= form.label 'label text' %>
<br/>
<%= form.my_boolean_field :my_boolean,
  {value: params['param_name'],
  class: 'form-control'}
%>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("my_boolean_field_JS_id").onchange = (event) => {
        window.location.search = `param_name=${event.target.value}`
      }
    </script>
```